# How can we script/automate firebug --> Profile JavaScript, in Java so it can be run from outside the browser?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Firebug's "Profile Javascript option, provides a Realtime mesurement of userexperience related to the JavaScript function times. Is there a way to automate that so i can have the same functionality of Profiling my application from outside the browser.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? JavaScript is to Java as ham is to hamster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use firefug outside of the browsers. However, there are some other debuggers for javascript you can go for. Check out these posts:

- [Blackbird](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/)
- [JavaScript Profiler 2.0](http://www.imnmotion.com/documents/html/technical/dhtml/jsprof.html)
- [JavaScript Function Call Profiling](http://ejohn.org/blog/function-call-profiling/) (by John Resig)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but this may be helpful:  https://github.com/mape/node-profile